# How to configure storage when installing secondary OS?

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, system-installation, storage

I have a server that runs Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to install a second up to date Ubuntu system on the same machine. I have managed to shrink existing parititions and created a new one out of the free space - this is where I would like to install new OS. Currently, I am stuck at storage configuration page of the installation setup. How can I specify the partition where I want my new OS to be?

Comment: You've provided no specifics as to what you're trying to install; only that it's *alongside* an off-topic EOL/ESM release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu ISOs are available using *five* installers (`ubiquity`, `subiquity`, `calamares`, *debian installer* & even a *canary* installer but you've given no details as to what Ubuntu system you're actually installing).  You did tag server meaning `subiquity` or *di* are most likely, but even those two exist for some Server releases which you didn't provide; the installer selected by the ISO you download & thus use.

Comment: I am sorry for now providing enough information, as I am not quite sure how to identify this info. I have downloaded the ISO image for Ubuntu 22.04 from the official website (https://ubuntu.com/download/server) and created the mounting media on Windows 10 using Rufus.

Comment: @guiverc that link doesn't exactly cover what I needed, but the discussion there pointed me into the right direction (https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/465642#465642) Thanks for the pointer!